# Adding commas to strings in an array and rewriting to CSV in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, replace

I am looking to read in values from a one column CSV, find and replace all ">" characters with commas, and then write out to a multi-column CSV.

The following works for reading in, replacing, and appending to a new array but the CSV writer is writing out individual letters as columns. Any idea how to write back out with the newly appended commas as new columns?

```
import sys
import csv
import time

map_array = []
map_array_1 = []

reader = csv.reader(open('input_file.csv', 'rU'))

for row in reader:
    map_array.append(row)

for i in map_array:
    for j in i:
        hold = j.replace(">",",")
        map_array_1.append(hold)

writer = csv.writer(open('output_file.csv','wb'),delimiter=',')
for row in map_array_1:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You are defining the delimiter to be `,` and also explicitly replacing the `>` with `,`, there is no way for the parser to figure out which `,` is delimiter and which is not

Comment: If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, you will will make it easier for us to help you.  At a minimum you are missing example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a sample input file and what the output file should look like. This would help.